# Tangent space distance from manifold

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, manifolds

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth $k$ - dimensional manifold and a vector $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $h\in T_x M$ iff $dist\left( x + \varepsilon h , M\right) =o\left( \varepsilon \right)$

**Attempt**:
assume $dist\left( x + \varepsilon h , M\right) =o\left( \varepsilon \right)$, I want to construct a curve $\gamma :(-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M$ as  $$ \gamma(t) = x+th+\alpha(t)$$

where $\alpha(t)$ is a correction function (assumed to be smooth) that keeps $x+th+\alpha(t) \in M$ (obviously $\alpha(0) = 0$ ). Now the challenge is to show that $\alpha'(0)=0$ and I don't know how.

I think I'm ok with the other direction.

Thanks

Comment: I'd try to prove that if $h\notin T_xM$ then $\text{dist}(x+\epsilon h,M)/\epsilon\ge c$, for some $c>0$ and $\epsilon\to 0$. I see it geometrically more evident. In fact, you can write $h=u+v$ for $u\perp v$ and $u\in T_xM$. Since $\text{dist}(x+\epsilon h, T_xM)= \epsilon |v|$  and the distance from the tangent space to the manifold is $\approx \epsilon^2|u|^2$, I'd conclude the result. You may want to formalize this heuristic.

Comment: How do I show that "the distance from the tangent space to the manifold is $\approx\varepsilon^2|u|^2$"?

Comment: Dear @Uria, I asserted that quite loosely, but since $u\in T_xM$, there is a curve $\gamma\subset M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=u$, so writing $\gamma$ in the coordinates $T_xM+N_xM$, where $N_xM=T_xM^{\perp}$, we get $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\ldots,\gamma_n(t))$ and $u=(u_1,\ldots, u_k,0,\ldots)$. By Taylor $\gamma(\epsilon)=x+\epsilon u+o(\epsilon)$, hence $\text{dist}(x+\epsilon u, M)=o(\epsilon)$. This suffices, I think, to prove both results :)